# Angular proxy config not working for multiple APIs

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-services

When I am setting up multiple target proxy am getting 404 though single one is working fine.

My Angular CLI version: 12.0.5

I need to call two APIs without using proxy config am getting CORS error. I am able to run single API.

My proxy:

```
{
    "/first/api/": {
        "target": "http://ipaddr1:5000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    },
    "/second/api/": {
        "target": "http://ipaddr2:5000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Angular service:

```
  getCarDetails(data: any) {
    return this.http.post<any>('/first/api/text/analytics/v2.0', JSON.stringify(payload))
  }

  getOthers(input: any) {
    return this.http.get<any>('/second/api/luis/v2.0/apps')
  }
```

How to write multiple target APIs.

Comment: CORS error is not a Front-End issue. Please, add some Backend relevant code and remove the uselss tags.

Comment: I can't make CORS backend changes because i am consuming microsoft public api . its issue with Angular config proxy . i am able to set single api proxy and it's working but when i set multiple taget ,its throwing 404